# Pandas Boxplot X-Axis Column Labels Overlapping, no title or labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm using .boxplot() on a dataframe that I've created and am getting the following output in the console.  Is there anyway to fix the axis such that the labels aren't overlapping?

Also how would you go about having the plot area bigger, or have it popout like when using matplotlib.  I tried to use plt.boxplot(df) plt.show() but am getting a 'unhashable type: 'slice'' error...

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please provide the data and code used to generate the plot.  Or at least a representative sample of the data. It'll be a lot easier to help you with specific syntax that way.

Comment: You can use the `figsize` argument in Pandas `plot()` methods to increase the size.  `df.boxplot(..., figsize=(15,8))`